# Can't access main setting Ubuntu 18.04LTS

Tags: system-settings

Can't access main setting Ubuntu 18.04LTS. tried gnome-control-center but display
Package gnome-control-center is not available etc.

[image: Screenshot of Terminal]

Comment: Does this work? `sudo apt remove gnome-control-center gnome-control-center-data` and then `sudo apt install gnome-control-center`

Comment: it didn't worked. display E:Package gnome-control-center can't be found.

Comment: Problem resolved , I found gnome-control-center in Ubuntu Software and installed.It is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Install Gnome-control-center from Ubuntu software

[image: Ubuntu Software - GNOME Control Center]